# How to filter the table and paste the value in another sheet in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

[image]

I would like to get value from the user and filter the table. I am filtering Column A (EP Number). Then copy the entire row to another sheet. If there is more than one row, copy both the rows and paste in different sheet.

I used the code below. Its not working and showing Type mismatch error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim str1 As String

str1 = Application.InputBox("Enter EP Number")
If CStr(str1) Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "str1", Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("A10:E10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("Table2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("J7").Select
Else
    MsgBox ("Wrong EP")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: First change `Criteria1:= "str1"` to `Criteria1:= str1`. Remove double quote from `str1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, since you are trying to check the `AutoFilter` Criteria with your variable `str1`, you need to take it outside the double-quote `"`, it need to be `Criteria1:=str1`.

**Second**, avoid all the unecessary `Select` and `ActiveSheet`, instead use fully qualifed objects.

You can use the `Dim Tbl As ListObject` , later set it explicitly by `Set Tbl = Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table1")`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim str1 As String
Dim Tbl As ListObject
Dim FiltRng As Range
Dim RngArea As Range

' set the List Object "Table1"
Set Tbl = Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table1")

str1 = Application.InputBox("Enter EP Number")

Tbl.Range.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=str1

' when using Filtered range, the range can be splitted to several areas >> loop through each one of them
For Each RngArea In Tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
    ' don't use the Header Row
    If RngArea.Row > 1 Then
        If Not FiltRng Is Nothing Then
            Set FiltRng = Application.Union(FiltRng, RngArea)
        Else
            Set FiltRng = RngArea
        End If
    End If
Next RngArea

If Not FiltRng Is Nothing Then ' filter range is not empty
    FiltRng.Copy
Else
    MsgBox "No Records match in the Table", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

' do here your paste thing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. Filtering alone works but copy and paste to diffrent sheet is not working. I tried it.
And always getting the message in Msgbox. How to solve it. Help me

Comment: @Deepak try now the edited code, I removed a part which was not needed, and adjusted the parameter of `If FiltRng.Rows.Count >= 1 Then`. It should work now

Comment: Thanks again. Now the filter, copy & paste works. But when i entered a value wrong, its not showing the message in msgbox.
I am getting this error "object or variable with block not set" and by table is going invisible. How to solve it. help me.

Comment: Thanks again. Code works. But i need to add clearcontents and clearfilter. Where to add that.
Because when i am calculating for the second time, sometimes the old data is still there.

Comment: @Deepak this sounds like a great new post for **SO** in the meantime, please accept this as "ANSWER" as I have answered all aspects of this current post